# Place text behind button inside table row

Tags: html, css

What I want to archive is to have text `Update-state` behind first button. They are all in one table. What is wrong there?

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class = "table table-striped  table-hover">
  <tr>
    <th>Actions</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="form-list vertical">
        <div class="horizontal">
          <div class="form-actions no-color">
            <input class="loader-button small-button" type="submit" value="Update" />
          </div>
          <div class="button-state">
            Update-state
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-actions no-color">
          <input class="loader-button small-button" type="submit" value="Restore" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions no-color">
          <input class="loader-button small-button" type="submit" value="Backup" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jmvekszc/)

Comment: `div` have `display:block` by default …

Comment: What do you mean by behind? On the same row to the right?

Comment: Do you use Bootstrap? Which version?

Answer (score 0):

I have added some css to take the Update-state backward. hope this might help you.

```
  <style>
    .container {
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    .table{
      min-width:100%;
    }
    .horizontal{
      position:relative;
      min-width:100%;
    }
    .horizontal .form-actions.no-color{
      position:relative;
      z-index:10;
    }
    .horizontal .form-actions.no-color + .button-state{
      position:absolute;
      z-index:0;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      min-width:100%;
    }
    </style>
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class = "table table-striped  table-hover">
      <tr>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="form-list vertical">
            <div class="horizontal">
              <div class="form-actions no-color">
                <input class="loader-button small-button" type="submit" value="Update--1" />
              </div>
              <div class="button-state">
                Update-state
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-actions no-color">
              <input class="loader-button small-button" type="submit" value="Restore" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-actions no-color">
              <input class="loader-button small-button" type="submit" value="Backup" />
            </div>
        </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.horizontal > * {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class = "table table-striped  table-hover">
  <tr>
    <th>Actions</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="form-list vertical">
        <div class="horizontal">
          <div class="form-actions no-color">
            <input class="loader-button small-button" type="submit" value="Update" />
          </div>
          <div class="button-state">
            Update-state
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="form-actions no-color">
          <input class="loader-button small-button" type="submit" value="Restore" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions no-color">
          <input class="loader-button small-button" type="submit" value="Backup" />
        </div>
    </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```